# Python plugin installation instructions I don't understand, can someone explain?

Tags: python

I'm trying to install python plugin for Trac.

Being a noob, I don't quite understand instructions...

Can someone please explain?

```
$> svn co https://www.coderesort.com/svn/open/trac-talkplugin/trunk tractalk-trunk
$> cd tractalk-trunk
$> python setup.py install # or 'bdist_egg' or 'develop'
```

Checkout from SVN - Done

cd tractalk-trunk - Done

**I'm stuck with installer.**

Should I run it exactly how it is written?

Or just python setup.py install ?

Care explain what is going on in this command?

As far as I understand # means that part is ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That command line invokes [the installer](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html) that is included with the package. Everything after the `#` is a comment and won't affect the shell, so you don't need to write it out.